# Zigconnect Plugin: Allowing editors to remove connections

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I'm using the [ZigConnect plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/zigconnect/) to set relationships between different types of posts. It appears that editors do not have the ability to remove connections, although this works fine for admins. How can I enable editors to remove connections?

Also, I have the [User Role Editor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) installed, but I’m not sure which capability would allow an editor to remove a connection.

I'm using WordPress 3.1.4 Multisite and Zigconnect plugin version 0.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the user the capability `manage_options`, however this will allow them to edit all options within wordpress.
The best bet will be to change all the capabilites checks from `manage_options` to `level_7` or some other editor capability(like `edit_others_posts` ) within the plugin.

(Found 12 matches, 7 on `zigconnect\zigconnect.php` and 5 on `zigconnect\zigconnect-admincallbacks.php` )